# How to setup a ruboto project in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruboto

I am trying to set up my development environment for a basic Ruboto project on Ubuntu. I've installed the the ruboto gem and run the `ruboto setup` command and this is what I get back.

```
Java runtime             : Found
Java Compiler            : Found
Apache ANT               : Found
Android Package Installer: Not found
Android Emulator         : Not found
Android SDK Command adb  : Not found
Android SDK Command dx   : Not found
Platform SDK android-16  : Not found

!!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!

Android package installer not found.
Would you like to download and install it? (Y/n): 

F, [2016-07-03T17:15:36.805497 #9102] FATAL -- : undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Even though i have already installed the android sdk and added it to PATH. I've followed the steps in this tutorial to set up the environment but I am still having issues.

https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Environment-setup-for-ubuntu

I have previously installed ruby version 2.3.0 using rvm and when I run the command echo $PATH i get back:

```
/home/qasim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/home/qasim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/home/qasim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/qasim/.rvm/bin:/snap/bin:/home/qasim/.rvm/bin:/android-sdk-linux/tools:/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/home/qasim/.rvm/bin
```

Any help would be much appreciated.